# Android | AlertBuilder Getting String text from values + method

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to display a text in Alert Dialog from Strings/string.xml and depending on the results within the app, an additional text.

**string.xml**

```
dialog_title = "Hello world"
dialog_message = "I am the text from string.xml"
```

**my alert dialog**

```
alertBuilder
              .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
              .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message + myClass.getText())
              .setCancelable(false)
```

**my getText() method**

```
public class myClass {
    public String getText() {      
    return "I am the text from the method" + "\n" + "I am a text from there, too"
    }
}
```

Output:

**Hello world**

**21283932323**

**I am the text from the method**

**I am a text from there, too**

__

Whats wrong here? Why am I getting a number instead of the text from string.xml?

Comment: R.string.dialog_message is a reference to the string, not the string itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are referencing to id of string.dialog in that way

try:

```
myClass.getText().concat(R.string.dialog);
```

OR

```
getString(R.string.dialog).concat(myClass.getText());
```

I hope it help you:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource?hl=es-419#java